# Install JRE without browser launch

Tags: java, nsis

I'm installing JRE using this command line in my NSIS script:

```
jre-7u45-windows-x64.exe /passive REBOOT=Suppress JAVAUPDATE=0 WEBSTARTICON=0 /L
```

this is no silent installation, as I want the user to see the install progress etc.

it works fine, but there is a huge annoyance.

When the JRE installer finishes it launches the web browser with this web page:

```
http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp
```

Is there any way to prevent the JRE browser launch?

Answer (score 0):

See this for Offline installation options: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-windows-141940.html

Then adjust command line for executing jre/jdk installer from NSIS script.

Good luck. Report back your progress, if you may. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but as I understand - the call to default(?) web browser is pretty much built-in. If that is so, then offline installation should not open such web browser. Though ... on the time of writing I was not rechecking current behaviour, so it may be changed... dunno. Sorry for misleading anyway ;).

Comment: the offline installation does open the default browser after install. This is the whole point of my post.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you already have a JRE installer and you want to change its behaviour from the one you're developing. This is not possible since you don't have control over the installation script that created the JRE installer. The only workaround is to roll your own JRE installer - but you'd have to know exactly what else it does besides copying files.

Comment: I'm using the standard installer from here http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=81821 it was just renamed from jre-7u45-windows-x64.exe to jre_setup.exe

Comment: Yeah, the point is that you just have the final bundled exe. Unless you have access to the InstallShield (or whatever) script that created the exe, you can't change its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

One very strange possibility is to use /s option and provide your own visual feedback: either static, or dynamic by looking for expected files that are created in expected locations.